# Recursive SQL statement without temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a working recursive SQL statement. Due to some restriction in my system, I need to reformulate it such that it is starting with "select count".

The idea behind the statement is to navigate from a certain point in a tree to find all endpoint of all branches underneath this point.

It would be fantastic if you have an idea.

Here my statement:

```
WITH temp_Parent_ID (Parent_productgroup_id, Productgroup_id) AS    
(
    SELECT 
        Parent_productgroup_id, Productgroup_id 
    FROM 
        VW_PRODUCTGROUP_HIERARCHY 
    WHERE 
        Productgroup_id = 26976

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        VW.Parent_productgroup_id, VW.Productgroup_id
    FROM 
        VW_PRODUCTGROUP_HIERARCHY VW    
    INNER JOIN 
        temp_Parent_ID temp ON VW.Parent_productgroup_id = temp.Productgroup_id
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(ae.element_ID) 
FROM 
    temp_Parent_ID temp 
INNER JOIN 
    VW_PRODUCTS_HIERARCHY VW ON temp.Productgroup_id = VW.PRODUCTGROUP_ID
INNER JOIN
    VW_PRODUCTS_ASSIGNED_E ae ON VW.PRODUCTVARIANT_ID = ae.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    VW_CATEGORY_ELEMENTS ce ON ae.ELEMENT_ID = ce.ELEMENT_ID
WHERE
    ce.CATEGORY_MASTER_NAME LIKE 'Technische Zeichnung (DWG)'
    AND ce.CATEGORY_LANGUAGE LIKE 'da'
```

Comment: needs more details. what db are you using? what are the schemas? what output are you expecting?

Comment: it is a mssql db and the excpected output is just a number. What schema do you need?
The recursion is through VW_PRODUCTGROUP_HIERARCHY with parent_product_group and product_group. To find all PRODUCTVARIANT_ID underneath the listed product_groups

Comment: As a result: I expect the number of productvariant (the endpoint) which have an assigned element, this is why we join VW_product_assigned_e. 
If we solve the task to count the number of productvariants unterneath a certain point in the tree we have solved the task.

Comment: "Due to some restriction in my system...."  What restriction?

Comment: What you are saying is that the query must start not start with `WITH`, but with `SELECT` instead?

Comment: I need to reformulate it such that it is starting with "select count". This is the restriction

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner
 How do you want to replace the "WITH"? I didn't know how to use select at this place...

Answer (score 0):

You need the `WITH` clause, because you need a recursive query. A `WITH` clause cannot be moved to another place in a query in SQL Server. That is a restriction specific to SQL Server, so this for instance is not possible:

```
select *
from ( with x as (select 1 as col) select * from x ) t;
```

A `WITH` clause is an ad-hoc view. Hence the only option I see for SQL Server is to make this a normal view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_products AS
WITH temp_Parent_ID (Parent_productgroup_id, Productgroup_id) AS    
(
    SELECT 
        Parent_productgroup_id, Productgroup_id 
    FROM 
        VW_PRODUCTGROUP_HIERARCHY 
    WHERE 
        Productgroup_id = 26976

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        VW.Parent_productgroup_id, VW.Productgroup_id
    FROM 
        VW_PRODUCTGROUP_HIERARCHY VW    
    INNER JOIN 
        temp_Parent_ID temp ON VW.Parent_productgroup_id = temp.Productgroup_id
)
select * from temp_Parent_ID;
```

And then use this view in your query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ae.element_ID) 
FROM 
    view_products
INNER JOIN 
    VW_PRODUCTS_HIERARCHY VW ON view_products.Productgroup_id = VW.PRODUCTGROUP_ID
INNER JOIN
    VW_PRODUCTS_ASSIGNED_E ae ON VW.PRODUCTVARIANT_ID = ae.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    VW_CATEGORY_ELEMENTS ce ON ae.ELEMENT_ID = ce.ELEMENT_ID
WHERE
    ce.CATEGORY_MASTER_NAME LIKE 'Technische Zeichnung (DWG)'
    AND ce.CATEGORY_LANGUAGE LIKE 'da'
```

Comment: Oh, I was afraid you are saying that.
Thanks a lot for answering that detailed